# How to grid columns in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid-layout

I'm making a project using tkinter but am having some trouble with using the grid method

i'm trying to place all the pictures on the right side of the screen,but its just not working

here is the code i've written:

```
window = Tk()

window.geometry("500x400")

lemon_pic = PhotoImage(file="lemon.png")
melon_pic = PhotoImage(file="melon.png")
dragonFruit_pic = PhotoImage(file="DragonFruit.png")

lemon_picture = Label(window,image=lemon_pic,bg="white") 
melon_picture = Label(window,image=melon_pic,bg="white")
DragonFruit_picture = Label(window,image=dragonFruit_pic,bg="white")

lemon_picture.grid(row=4,column=10,sticky=E) 
melon_picture.grid(row=0,column=10,sticky=E)
DragonFruit_picture.grid(row=3,column=10,sticky=E)


window.mainloop()
```

And here's the output i get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV1kn.png

Comment: It may be because there is nothing in the columns before column 10, so their widths are all zero.

Comment: I did my research and a lot of what i've found say the same as you did, but how can i fix it? how can i make the images visible in column 10.

Comment: Use `win.columnconfigure(10, weight=1)` (assume `win` is the container of the widgets holding the images) and set `sticky=E` on the `.grid(...)`.

Comment: i just tried it, It works! but only on column 10..so if i were to put column 9 or 8 it wouldn't work

Comment: Then change 10 to the column in `.columnconfigure(...)`.

Comment: thanks, That works well!

i have another question, Can we separate each picture by half a row only? 

if i tried to do something like `lemon_picture.grid(row=0.5,column=10,sticky=E)`

it would give me an error saying that i should provide a non-negative integer
`bad row value "0.5": must be a non-negative integer`

Comment: You  can add `pady` option to `.grid(...)` to add some margins.

Comment: okay! Thanks a lot for answering my question,Sorry if it was a silly one

so how do i mark this question as solved?

Comment: you should vote on it and/or accept it, also if you have something else to ask, create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

if the images are inside a frame that is sticky to the left like `frame.pack(side='left')`: then change that to `'right'`. otherwise:
try using `E` (east) instead of `W` (west) for the images

```py
lemon_picture.grid(row=0,column=10,sticky=E) 
melon_picture.grid(row=1,column=10,sticky=E)
DragonFruit_picture.grid(row=2,column=10,sticky=E)
```

Comment: I tried doing so and it still doesn't work

Comment: i don't use frame.pack() at all and i don't know how to use it...is it gonna help me with fixing this if i use it?

Comment: it may be esier to fix the problem if you edit your question to include all your code

Comment: @acw1668 answered my question, Thank you a lot for helping me.